# unable to create form for has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a blog post and I want to add a  box which has one time description such that one book can have only one detail and after submitting that form it will disappear.
My issue is that I have checked my association it is working in console I am just unable to set my form according to it as It gives error

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

My Book model

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :sub_demo
end
```

My Subdemo model

```
class SubDemo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
end
```

my routes

```
 resources :books do
    resources :sub_demo
 end
```

my form

```
<%= form_with model:  ([@book, @book.sub_demo.build]), local:true do |form|%>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= form.label :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= form.label :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= form.text_area :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="text-start">
    <%= form.submit :class => "btn btn-info btn-sm" %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

So in the nested routes the name sub_demo is same but I am still getting the error.

Comment: have you called @book.new in you controller? try to build the sub_demo in controller as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow your goal entirely, but the problem is this:

```
@book.sub_demo.build
```

`sub_demo` there is nil, so when you call `build` on it, you get the error:

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

The [`has_one`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) association provides a convenient method to create an associate object and it's `build_#{association_name}`. So in this case you want to call:

```
@book.build_sub_demo
```

The way you find that out is in the documentation here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one

[image]